# How do I get GitHub Pages to re-render my React App?

Tags: git, reactjs, github, github-pages

I am currently having an issue having my React App re-render when I commit changes to my GitHub. I believe that the way GitHub Pages works with React is that it runs from a `bundle.js` file from a `gh-pages` branch of your GitHub. I have read from many StackOverflow questions that when I commit my changes, the website should update automatically, but this does not work at all.

On deeper thought this seems to make sense to me because my `gh-pages` branch is not being updated, it is the branch that I work on that is being committed to. When I first properly built and deployed my website, GitHub created the `gh-pages` branch on its own, so as far as I know there is no way to commit to it anyways. Does anyone know how I'm supposed to be updating my website properly? Currently I am only able to do this by rerunning the build/deploy command, and I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to do that more than a few times an hour.

Thank you!

Edit:

Here is a link to my GitHub branch that hosts the files for the GitHub Pages website:

https://github.com/NumaKarolinski/PersonalWebsite/tree/websiteVersion1

Here is a link to my GitHub Pages branch:

https://github.com/NumaKarolinski/PersonalWebsite/tree/gh-pages

Comment: do you have a repository link? could be a config error

Comment: I forgot to add that. I'll edit it in.